# How to remove element of list based on condition in the sublist

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I have the following list of list:

```
list_of_list = [["-", " ", "P"], ["-", " ", "L"], ["-", " ", "R"], ["K", "|", "K"], ["K", "|", "K"], ["I", " ", "-"], ["K", "|", "K"], ["-", " ", "K"], ["-", " ", "V"], ["-", " ", "D"], ["-", " ", "P"], ["-", " ", "K"], ["-", " ", "K"], ["-", " ", "D"], ["-", " ", "Q"], ["-", " ", "E"], ["A", "|", "A"], ["N", " ", "-"], ["-", " ", "K"], ["-", " ", "E"], ["R", "|", "R"], ["-", " ", "L"], ["-", " ", "K"], ["R", "|", "R"], ["S", " ", "-"], ["N", " ", "-"], ["S", " ", "-"], ["K", "|", "K"], ["-", " ", "I"], ["-", " ", "R"], ["K", "|", "K"], ["-", " ", "L"], ["-", " ", "E"]]
```

Which looks like this:

```
In [48]: list_of_list
Out[48]:
[['-', ' ', 'P'], # remove this
 ['-', ' ', 'L'], # remove this
 ['-', ' ', 'R'], # remove this
 ['K', '|', 'K'],
 ['K', '|', 'K'],
 ['I', ' ', '-'],
 ['K', '|', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'V'],
 ['-', ' ', 'D'],
 ['-', ' ', 'P'],
 ['-', ' ', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'D'],
 ['-', ' ', 'Q'],
 ['-', ' ', 'E'],
 ['A', '|', 'A'],
 ['N', ' ', '-'],
 ['-', ' ', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'E'],
 ['R', '|', 'R'],
 ['-', ' ', 'L'],
 ['-', ' ', 'K'],
 ['R', '|', 'R'],
 ['S', ' ', '-'],
 ['N', ' ', '-'],
 ['S', ' ', '-'],
 ['K', '|', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'I'],
 ['-', ' ', 'R'],
 ['K', '|', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'L'],  # remove this
 ['-', ' ', 'E']]  # remove this
```

As shown in the output above, what I want to do is to remove the element of the beginning and the end of the list. In the beginning, we remove all the lists where the 2nd element is empty until it finds `|`.  In the end, we remove all the list after the last `|` found is empty.

The desired output is this:

```
[['K', '|', 'K'],
 ['K', '|', 'K'],
 ['I', ' ', '-'],
 ['K', '|', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'V'],
 ['-', ' ', 'D'],
 ['-', ' ', 'P'],
 ['-', ' ', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'D'],
 ['-', ' ', 'Q'],
 ['-', ' ', 'E'],
 ['A', '|', 'A'],
 ['N', ' ', '-'],
 ['-', ' ', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'E'],
 ['R', '|', 'R'],
 ['-', ' ', 'L'],
 ['-', ' ', 'K'],
 ['R', '|', 'R'],
 ['S', ' ', '-'],
 ['N', ' ', '-'],
 ['S', ' ', '-'],
 ['K', '|', 'K'],
 ['-', ' ', 'I'],
 ['-', ' ', 'R'],
 ['K', '|', 'K']]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just slicing:

```
s = ''.join(b for a,b,c in list_of_list)
list_of_list[s.find('|'):s.rfind('|')+1]
```

Comment: Wow!, i never new that there was a function called `rindex` for strings, Now i know, You just thought me `rindex`

Comment: This will not work if `|` does not exist in the input i.e `list_of_list = [['-', ' ', 'P'], ['asd', ' ', 'J']]`. A `ValueError: substring not found` will be raised.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Changed to `rfind` instead, which would return empty list in that case (not sure what OP would prefer, though).  FWIW your code would raise exception too - `ValueError: not enough values to unpack`.

Comment: @wim My first solution would with `itertools.groupby`, however, my second solution does not. `itertools.groupby` is cleaner and works should the input be guaranteed to start and end with lists containing spaces.

Comment: @Ajax1234  So your first solution and second solution don't actually return equivalent results for the edge case - you should probably mention that they have a difference in behaviour in the answer. And seems the OP can't use your first solution anyway because it only works on Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing + `enumerate`:

```
l=[i for i,v in enumerate(list_of_list) if v[1]=='|']
l2=list_of_list[l[0]:l[-1]+1]
print(l2)
```

Output:

```
[['K', '|', 'K'], ['K', '|', 'K'], ['I', ' ', '-'], ['K', '|', 'K'], ['-', ' ', 'K'], ['-', ' ', 'V'], ['-', ' ', 'D'], ['-', ' ', 'P'], ['-', ' ', 'K'], ['-', ' ', 'K'], ['-', ' ', 'D'], ['-', ' ', 'Q'], ['-', ' ', 'E'], ['A', '|', 'A'], ['N', ' ', '-'], ['-', ' ', 'K'], ['-', ' ', 'E'], ['R', '|', 'R'], ['-', ' ', 'L'], ['-', ' ', 'K'], ['R', '|', 'R'], ['S', ' ', '-'], ['N', ' ', '-'], ['S', ' ', '-'], ['K', '|', 'K'], ['-', ' ', 'I'], ['-', ' ', 'R'], ['K', '|', 'K']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
def remove_elements(l):
  new_data = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x:x[1] == ' ')]
  _, *content, _end = new_data
  return [c for _, c in content]

list_of_list = [["-", " ", "P"], ["-", " ", "L"], ["-", " ", "R"], ["K", "|", "K"], ["K", "|", "K"], ["I", " ", "-"], ["K", "|", "K"], ["-", " ", "K"], ["-", " ", "V"], ["-", " ", "D"], ["-", " ", "P"], ["-", " ", "K"], ["-", " ", "K"], ["-", " ", "D"], ["-", " ", "Q"], ["-", " ", "E"], ["A", "|", "A"], ["N", " ", "-"], ["-", " ", "K"], ["-", " ", "E"], ["R", "|", "R"], ["-", " ", "L"], ["-", " ", "K"], ["R", "|", "R"], ["S", " ", "-"], ["N", " ", "-"], ["S", " ", "-"], ["K", "|", "K"], ["-", " ", "I"], ["-", " ", "R"], ["K", "|", "K"], ["-", " ", "L"], ["-", " ", "E"]]
print(remove_elements(list_of_list))
```

Output:

```
[[['K', '|', 'K'], ['K', '|', 'K']], [['I', ' ', '-']], [['K', '|', 'K']], [['-', ' ', 'K'], ['-', ' ', 'V'], ['-', ' ', 'D'], ['-', ' ', 'P'], ['-', ' ', 'K'], ['-', ' ', 'K'], ['-', ' ', 'D'], ['-', ' ', 'Q'], ['-', ' ', 'E']], [['A', '|', 'A']], [['N', ' ', '-'], ['-', ' ', 'K'], ['-', ' ', 'E']], [['R', '|', 'R']], [['-', ' ', 'L'], ['-', ' ', 'K']], [['R', '|', 'R']], [['S', ' ', '-'], ['N', ' ', '-'], ['S', ' ', '-']], [['K', '|', 'K']], [['-', ' ', 'I'], ['-', ' ', 'R']], [['K', '|', 'K']]]
```

Or slightly longer solution, although more robust:

```
_start = [i for i in range(len(l)) if all(c[1] == ' ' for c in l[:i])]
_end = [i for i in range(len(l)) if all(c[1] == ' ' for c in l[i:])]
new_l = l[0 if not _start else _start[-1]:len(l) if not _end else _end[-1]-1]
```

Comment: I get `invalid syntax` for `*content` I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: @scamander `*content` is only valid in Python3. However, my solution below it will work for both versions.

Comment: `l[:i]` and `l[i:]` is copying the list on every iteration.  That's O(n^2) worst case. Also you talk about enumerate (which would have been better) but never used it.

Comment: @wim Ah yes, removed mention of `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

Just play with indexes

```
def ind(l):
    for i,v in enumerate(l):
        if v[1]=="|": return i

ll = ll[ind(ll):]
ll[::-1][ind(ll[::-1]):][::-1]
```